LNCS: Using et. al. in reference list
The llncs document class (Overleaf template) lists all authors name in the References section by default.
How do I change this so where there are more than 3 authors, it should be in the form: FirstAuthor, et. al. (without listing all the authors, to preserve space).
So instead of (which runs into 3 lines):
Alcobaça, E., Siqueira, F., Rivolli, A., Garcia, L.P., Oliva, J.T., De Carvalho, A.C.: MFE: Towards reproducible meta-feature extraction. Journal of Machice Learning Research 21(111), 1–5 (2020)
It is formatted to (to fit into just 2 lines):
Alcobaça, E. et. al: MFE: Towards reproducible meta-feature extraction. Journal of Machice Learning Research 21(111), 1–5 (2020)
EDIT
MWE in (following) code:
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[maxnames=3]{biblatex}

\begin{document}
%
\title{Contribution Title}

\author{First Author\inst{1}\orcidID{0000-1111-2222-3333} \and
Second Author\inst{2,3}\orcidID{1111-2222-3333-4444} \and
Third Author\inst{3}\orcidID{2222--3333-4444-5555}}
%
\authorrunning{F. Author et al.}
%
\institute{Princeton University, Princeton NJ 08544, USA \and
Springer Heidelberg, Tiergartenstr. 17, 69121 Heidelberg, Germany
\email{lncs@springer.com}\\
\url{http://www.springer.com/gp/computer-science/lncs} \and
ABC Institute, Rupert-Karls-University Heidelberg, Heidelberg, Germany\\
\email{\{abc,lncs\}@uni-heidelberg.de}}
%
\maketitle             
%

\lipsum[1]
%
\begin{thebibliography}{8}
\bibitem{ref_article1}
Alcobaça, E., Siqueira, F., Rivolli, A., Garcia, L.P., Oliva, J.T., De Carvalho, A.C.: MFE: Towards reproducible meta-feature extraction. Journal of Machice Learning Research 21(111), 1–5 (2020)

\bibitem{ref_article2}
Author, F.: Article title. Journal \textbf{2}(5), 99--110 (2016)

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document} 

But this didn't change anything.
Output:

How do I modify the package to do this.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Have you verified that the llncs document class can employ the biblatex package?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz question edited with a sample (complete) code.

@Mico Apparently yes, as it does work in the MWE shared in the edit above.

@AminaUmar If you are manually creating the references in a thebibliography environment, you can manually delete the additional authors there and add "et al."

@AminaUmar - Since your test file (a) doesn't contain any \cite instructions, (b) doesn't contain an \addbibresource instruction, (c) doesn't contain a \printbibliography instruction, and (d) creates the thebibliography environment entirely by hand, the instruction \usepackage[maxnames=3]{biblatex} simply does nothing. Hence, you have not demonstrated that the llncs document class can employ biblatex meaningfully.

Off-topic: (a) The trunction string is "et al.", not "et. al."; observe that "et al." is short for "et alii", which is Latin for "and others". (b) Please be sure to change Machice Learning to Machine Learning.

@Mico thank you. This is well noted.
